# Bind JQuery event to html created after pageload via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am developing a jquery module for add delete edit view etc.
My problem is when page load complete, a list of items populate. After selecting an item this item's subitems loaded via jquery and html built, appended. But on this table event not fired up. Jquery Live is no longer available. Instead "On" is not working.

I tried :

```
$(document).on('click', selector , function () { foo(); });
```

But when a button is clicked it triggers other buttons as well.

My code is below.
I have a working code except links on table which loaded by jquery.

```
var myModule = {
    el: {
        listbutton: $('#list-button'),
        listcontainer: $('#list'),
        detailbutton: $(".item-detail"),
        deletebutton: $(".item-delete"),
        editbutton: $(".item-edit")
    },  
     init: function() {
     ...
     myModule.el.listbutton.on("click",myModule.getMainData);
    },

    getMainData: function() {
        ...
        success: function(data) {
                myModule.BuildTable(data.Value.DataList);
        }
        ...
    },
    BuildTable: function (hws) {
        var c = "";
        c += "<table>";
        $.each(hws, function() {
            c +=
                '<tr>' +
                    '<td>' + this.Title + '</td>' +
                    '<td><a href="#" class="item-detail"></a></td>' +
                    '<td><a href="#" class="item-edit"></a></td>' +
                    '<td><a href="#" class="item-delete"></a></td>' +
                '<tr>';
        });
        c += "</table>";
        myModule.el.listcontainer.empty().append(c);
        myModule.TableLinks();
    },

    itemDetails: function () {
        alert("Detail clicked");
    },
    itemDelete: function () {
        alert("Delete clicked");
    },
    itemEdit: function () {
        alert("Edit clicked");
    },

    TableLinks: function () {
        $(document).on('click', myModule.el.detailbutton, function () { myModule.itemDetails(); });
        $(document).on('click', myModule.el.deletebutton, function () { myModule.itemDelete(); });
        $(document).on('click', myModule.el.editbutton, function () { myModule.itemEdit(); });
    },

};

myModule.init();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try following:

```
  TableLinks: function () {
    $(document).on('click', 
            ".item-detail", 
            function (ev) { 
               myModule.itemDetails(); 
               ev.stopPropagation();
            }
    );
    $(document).on('click',
           ".item-delete",
           function (ev) {
               myModule.itemDelete(); 
               ev.stopPropagation();
           });
    $(document).on('click',
            ".item-edit",
            function (ev) { 
                   myModule.itemEdit(); 
                   ev.stopPropagation();
            });
   },
```

Comment: @gandil:please check following jsfiddle.[[link]http://jsfiddle.net/jforjava1981/PcSy5/4/                   is that what you want?its working fine. it basically creates two dynamic buttons on the click of a button. and evernt handlers are being called fine. if this is what you want please try changing dynamic references to selectors in "on" event delegation to hardcoded ones like for example  instead of  $(document).on('click', myModule.el.detailbutton, function () { myModule.itemDetails(); }); put  $(document).on('click', ".item-detail", function (ev) { myModule.itemDetails(); });

Comment: @gandil:I was right please check follwing fiddle the delegations stops working when I use dynamic references:[link]http://jsfiddle.net/jforjava1981/6dy9p/2/

Comment: all three link triggered again.

Comment: did you use my code? what did you change?Did you check my fiddles? Is it what you want? if yes then there is something amiss in other part of your code ? if possible can your send more details?

Comment: Yes I applied as you did. Your code is working but my is not. Can I send full code via email?

Comment: Sure.also if you are on skype. we can chat in real time if you are fine with that. for starters please send the code..my email is "jforjava1981@gmail.com"

Answer (score 1):

You have to do something like this to use the "on" method.

```
$("table").on("click", myModule.el.detailbutton, myModule.itemDetails());
```

UPDATE: Just noticed, you have to used a selector not a jQuery object in the second parameter.

So `$("table").on("click", ".item-detail", myModule.itemDetails());`

Answer (score 1):

you need the delegation

```
$("selector on which item is added").on("click", "new item selector", function(){    

});
```

### [ON](https://api.jquery.com/on/) and [Delegate](https://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

Answer (score 0):

your approach using `on` is exactly what you need, but should have been bit more careful on constructing the element object

```
el: {
    listbutton: '#list-button',
    listcontainer: '#list',
    detailbutton: ".item-detail",
    deletebutton: ".item-delete",
    editbutton: ".item-edit"
},
```

and use it like this

```
init: function () {
    $(myModule.el.listbutton).on("click", myModule.getMainData);
},
```

what you did is

```
TableLinks: function () {
    $(document).on('click', myModule.el.detailbutton, function () { myModule.itemDetails(); });
...
},
```

which is similar to and which is wrong

```
TableLinks: function () {
    $(document).on('click', $(".item-detail"), function () { myModule.itemDetails(); });
    ....
},
```

working [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Uy6de/)

Comment: I update my code as your instruction. But still when detail is clicked edit and delete also triggered.

Comment: also it does not matter where you clicked on any page. all three function triggered.

Comment: @gandil Are you sure? you checked the fiddle right? Still it does the same, try clearing the browser cache.